# What does this Boris Johnson article mean? How we can interpret it?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, russian-federation, media, boris-johnson

Recently, Boris Johnson wrote an article in response to Putin's speech about liberalism: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2019/06/30/will-prove-vladimir-putin-wrong-leaving-eu-october-31/

There is something, that surprised me - Boris Johnson is going to make Brexit to prove Putin wrong (don't understand how, but nevertheless). But some times ago, I heard that Brexit is fully inspired by Russia: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/jun/17/why-isnt-there-greater-outrage-about-russian-involvement-in-brexit

I found even a Wikipedia article about it. Truth or not - no one knows, but what does it mean? If Boris Johnson is against Putin, and wants to make him wrong - and on the other side - Russia (as heard in English press) started Brexit, on what side is Mr. Johnson?

I don't want to know his internal motivations. I'm just seeing a chaos and want to understand what is that.

Comment: Why off-topic?)

Comment: Should have a VTC option specifically for trying to interpret what Boris' says :-)

Comment: This question seems to be based on a while bunch of misconceptions

Comment: @Bad_Bishop, made my day with your joke)

Comment: @PhillS - emmm, what? So, western media politics is a misconception? What are you talking about??

Comment: Promote or discredit? Possible prime minister claims one thing, with talking about the opposite. What to discredit here?)

Comment: The **possibility** that either Russia will benefit strategically from Brexit or that Russia did actively support Brexit does not mean that anyone in the Brexit camp is automatically allied with Putin, and even if you believed that Mr. Johnson has some kind of agreement with Mr. Putin that does not mean that Mr. Johnson has to agree with everything Putin says. And of course, even if Mr. Putin had Mr. Johnson in his pocket, it would be convenient to sometimes make it appear as if it is not the case. Pick your choice.

Comment: Not everything in the world is black or white. People can agree on a course of action (like Putin and Johnson on Brexit) but arrive at that conclusion based on different motivations and/or different reasoning processes. In international politics there are never just two sides in a conflict. Agreeing with someone doesn't necessarily make them your friend, just as disagreeing with someone doesn't necessarily make them your enemy.

Comment: Good words, @Philipp. If only that was true on nowadays cold war, world might be much easier. I'll close question myself

Comment: It's Boris, most of what he says is mindless drivel that sounds sort-of clever but isn't. I don't think it's possible to draw any real conclusions from most of what he says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article is paywalled, so it's difficult to say what Johnson means, but to a great extent it doesn't matter. To an even greater extent than normal politicians, he doesn't mean what he says and lies freely about the EU.

Brexit is not primarily a Russian project. If anything I would say it's the result of a long, sustained campaign of disinformation about the EU by the British press. Including Boris Johnson:

> His articles, like those in several other Eurosceptic newspapers, contained many of the claims widely described as “Euromyths”, including plans to introduce same-size “eurocoffins”, establish a “banana police force” to regulate the shape of the curved yellow fruit, and ban prawn cocktail crisps.

[(Independent)](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/boris-johnson-lies-conservative-leader-candidate-list-times-banana-brexit-bus-a8929076.html)

Comment: Those dreadful erocrats want to ban our 'emulsified high fat offal tube' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euromyth#Eurosausage